# How does QuickFix use the data dictionary to map the field number to field name?

Tags: quickfix, data-dictionary

When I check the data dictionary https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix/blob/master/spec/FIX42.xml
[image]

It looks like to me that there are only field name and whether it is a required field or not.

But as I know, a FIX message is only a series of fields with key and value separated by delimiter

How can QuickFix map the field number to name as the data dictionary does not contains any info about the field number? I mean at least something like <field **number='8'** name='BeginString' required='Y' />

Or the FIX elements must be specified in order so that the data dictionary just maps them one by one in order? But if it is the case, how about one element is missing, then all the subsequent mappings go wrong?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't get the question. Am I missing something? Field names are mapped to numbers starting from here: https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix/blob/85bb8a9acae6b0e6a2c37d498e646a5437f23983/spec/FIX42.xml#L1603

Comment: That's in the same file that you mention in your post.

Comment: @ChristophJohn Thanks for your reminder, I see the row. I originally thought "<header><field name='BeginString' required='Y' />" is the only thing/definition of "BeginString", so I wonder how can QuickFix maps it to the number 8. If I understand correctly, "<header><field name='BeginString' required='Y' />" define what is the field (it is a header, not a message content) and if it is required while "<fields><field number='8' name='BeginString' type='STRING' />" defines the key number (8) and its type, where name='BeginString' is the linkage between them.

Comment: @ChristophJohn I would like to mark your one as answer, would you mind post your comment as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is basically in the same file that you mentioned in your post.

Field names are mapped to numbers starting from here: https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix/blob/85bb8a9acae6b0e6a2c37d498e646a5437f23983/spec/FIX42.xml#L1603